# HDF5 and GSL library problem on Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, environment-variables, libraries, configure

I ran into errors in the installation of the `FDTD` software [`MEEP`](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep) on Ubuntu.Although I have `hdf5-tools` and `libhdf5` installed on my system(Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit), the `make` step of the installation of `MEEP` returns an **error** as in this [paste.bin link](http://pastebin.com/fpFa3B5X). I configured `MEEP` with the following command:

```
./configure --with-mpi --with-hdf5=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  > configure.out
```

I then ran `make` which resulted in error and I could not run `make install` afterwards. Without specifying the `--with-hdf5` flag the configuration script used to return a warning as follows:

```
configure: WARNING: Couldn't find the HDF5 library!! Switching to ...
```

After installing numerous HDF5 libraries the problem was magically resolved; however, it was still present when I used the flag `--with-hdf5=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. But without the flag everything installed flawlessly(I tested the program afterwards and confirmed that it was running as expected.) except the GNU Scientific Library linkage. My questions are as follows:

1. How the location of the library can be located from the command prompt? Is executing the command `locate hdf5` in the case of HDF5 and the finding the path of files ending with `.so`, `.a` enough?
2. How could the GNU Scientific Library be introduced to the configuration and make scripts?
3. Do the `environmental variables` **LDFLAGS**, **CPPFLAGS** and **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** have anything to do with the configuration and make scripts recognizing these libraries. I think they have since they are mentioned in [MEEP install instructions](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep_Installation) and [MEEP install tutorial](http://juluribk.com/2013/07/20/installing-meep-1-2-on-ubuntu/). I would appreciate it if someone can explain how these and the **LIB** variable are related with installation procedures.

Thanks for taking your time,

P.S: If required I can supply additional documents. I did not put the configuration script etc. since I do not know which one is automatically generated and which one is not(same goes for `make`).

Comment: According to `./configure --help`, the `--with-hdf5` option seems to be boolean only (it doesn't take a `<dir>` argument). The hfd5 library should be discovered automatically provided you have installed the `libhdf5-dev` package in a "system" location (and possibly the appropriate `libhdf5-mpi-dev` if you are building `--with-mpi` i.e. either `libhdf5-mpich2-dev` or `libhdf5-openmpi-dev`).

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your comment. Apart from that how can I point out to GSL library? Furthermore, how are the other environmental variables related and are all the configure scripts alike since you told me this information without seeing the configure script?

Comment: I suspect it *is* finding the gsl library, but there is a wrinkle in exactly how it tests and reports it (specifically, that it does an `AC_CHECK_FUNC` rather than an `AC_CHECK_LIB` for the preceding `libgslcblas` library, which results in `libgslcblas` not getting added to `$LIBS`. However I don't know anywhere near enough about autoconf to say for sure.

Comment: @steeldriver I can provide the file if you wish or provide the link to the source directly.

Comment: Actually I already downloaded the `meep` tarball from the MIT website and had a play with it earlier.

Comment: @steeldriver Well thanks for your interest so together with GSL what should I have? How can I set `$LIBS` accordingly? Do these complications arise due to system architecture since it is 64-bit?

Comment: Give me a couple of hrs - if no-one has posted an answer I will try to add one, including a possible workaround

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks I am grateful for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To answer this question well really requires a thorough understanding of GNU `autotools`, which I don't have: nevertheless I hope these comments will help.*

The configure script for a particular build is generated from its configure.ac file using `autoconf`. In turn, configure.ac uses standard macros to test for the presence of specified components. In this particular case, configure.ac specifies an AC_CHECK_LIB test for the GSL library as

```
  AC_CHECK_LIB(gsl, gsl_sf_bessel_Jn, [],
        [AC_MSG_WARN([Missing GNU GSL library...Bessel-function field initialization will not be supported.])])
```

The [syntax of an AC_CHECK_LIB](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Libraries.html) is

```
AC_CHECK_LIB (library, function, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found], [other-libraries])
```

and the actual mechanism by which the check is performed is by creating a minimal test program (`conftest`) for the specified **function** `gsl_sf_bessel_Jn` in library `libgsl`, and attempting to link it using the default build tools. Such a minimal program might look something like

```
char gsl_sf_bessel_Jn();

int main() { return gsl_sf_bessel_Jn(); return 0; }
```

Note that the dummy prototype `char gsl_sf_bessel_Jn()` may bear no relation to the return type or argument list of the actual function - we never attempt to *run* the program, we just wish to know whether it links (i.e. whether the linker is able to resolve library references). We can see how this works if we create such a source file ourselves:

```
$ cat > conftest.c
char gsl_sf_bessel_Jn();

int main() { return gsl_sf_bessel_Jn(); return 0; }
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

As expected, if we try to run it *without* linking the GSL library, we get an error

```
$ gcc conftest.c
/tmp/ccWqFraS.o: In function `main':
conftest.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_bessel_Jn'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However **even if we explicitly link** `libgsl` we find

```
$ gcc conftest.c -lgsl
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sger'
.
<snip>
.
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zdotu_sub'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*At this point, it's important to note that the configure script doesn't know **why** a particular test has failed, only that it has.* In this case, it has failed because we didn't link the subordinate `libgslcblas` library.

This illustrates the importance of the order in which tests are performed: each successful test causes the newly discovered library to be added to the `$LIB` variable for subsequent tests. Specifically (as noted in [the GSL documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Autoconf-Macros.html))

> It is important to check for libm and libgslcblas before libgsl,
>   otherwise the tests will fail. Assuming the libraries are found the
>   output during the configure stage looks like this,
>
> ```
> checking for cos in -lm... yes 
> checking for cblas_dgemm in -lgslcblas... yes 
> checking for gsl_blas_dgemm in -lgsl... yes
> ```
>
> If the library is found then the tests will define the macros
>   HAVE_LIBGSL, HAVE_LIBGSLCBLAS, HAVE_LIBM and add the options -lgsl
>   -lgslcblas -lm to the variable LIBS.

---

The meep source package *does* check for libgslcblas before libgsl, however the specific check that it does is an AC_CHECK_FUNC rather than an AC_CHECK_LIB

```
AC_CHECK_FUNC(cblas_cgemm, [], [AC_CHECK_LIB(gslcblas, cblas_cgemm)])
```

While superficially similar, it appears that AC_CHECK_FUNC does not append the library to `$LIBS` on success; it appears we can work around this simply by adding an explicit AC_CHECK_LIB for libgslcblas in the configure.ac file

```
# GNU Scientific Library
AC_CHECK_FUNC(cblas_cgemm, [], [AC_CHECK_LIB(gslcblas, cblas_cgemm)])
AC_CHECK_LIB([gslcblas],[cblas_cgemm])
AC_CHECK_LIB(gsl, gsl_sf_bessel_Jn, [],
   [AC_MSG_WARN([Missing GNU GSL library...Bessel-function field initialization will not be supported.])])
```

and then running `autoconf` to regenerate the configure script

```
$ autoconf
```

after which running `./configure` reports that the the GSL library is indeed found:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local | grep gsl
configure: WARNING: Cannot find latex2html in your path!
configure: WARNING: FFTW needed for MPB
checking for cblas_cgemm in -lgslcblas... yes
checking for gsl_sf_bessel_Jn in -lgsl... yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I really appreciate the effort you put in writing these down.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install the packages from the http://packages.ubuntu.com/ repository. Ubuntu cache all the packages metadata in the computer. You can search your packages using the following command.

```
sudo apt-cache search "package keyword"
```

search the HDF5 library in the ubuntu package repository.

```
sudo apt-cache search "hdf5"
```

The command will show the packages relating to hdf5.

install the relevant package to you.

```
sudo apt-get install package-name.
```

mostly you have to install the hdf5-tools, h5utils, python-tables.